# How to find de Sitter and almost de Sitter solutions in (super)string theory

Tags: string-theory, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

From Cosmology, we have learned that we live in an almost de Sitter (positively accelerated!) Universe. It seems that dS space solutions in superstring/theory are problematic and there are some no-go theorems about it...The question is:

Can we found de Sitter space solutions or almost de Sitter space (asymptotically dS) solutions in the space of solutions of superstring/M theory? What could be the weak points of no-go de Sitter spaces in Superstring theory? How could we modify superstring theory in order to admit "naturally" dS vacua?

**Remark:** in terms of the superstring theory landscape, is there any almost dS space solution in superstring theories similar to the Universe, with a positive cosmological constant?

Comment: Didn't you [ask this before](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/cosmological-constant-positive-ds-as-susy-supertring-issue)?

Comment: [See also this answer from Luboš](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3141/).

Comment: Yes, but I am asking here more for possible "scape" to the issue of no dS spacetime solutions in (current) string theory...

Comment: Has the cosmological constant killed Supersymmetry and Superstring theory in its "standard" form?

Comment: see Susskind, section The Trouble with de Sitter Space: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0302219

Comment: and see Giudice et al, for more recent speculation that the Universe must be meta-stable because of these considerations, http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04825

Comment: @riemannium: no, because supersymmetry is broken. Luboš' answer to [the question I linked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/can-has-string-theory-solved-cosmological-constant-problem) point out that a positive cosmological constant can be obtained when supersymmetry is broken.

Comment: OK, but if SUSY is broken, we loose a motivation for SUSY...I read a lot about SUSY...Decades ago, it was said that one motivation for SUSY was to cancel the cosmological constant...Now we have lost that motivation, haven't we?

Comment: No. Supersymmetry must be broken at low energies. Obviously so since the universe around us isn't supersymmetric. String theorists have known this since the outset, and mechanisms for low energy supersymmetry breaking have been extensively studied.

Comment: What do you mean by "low energy"? Few Tevs? Hundreds of TeV's? The GUT or Planck scale? Something intermediate between the EW and the GUT/Planck scale?

Comment: By the other hand, the theory does NOT fix the supersymmetry scale breaking energy uniquely...

Comment: @riemannium: you need to do some reading around this area yourself. When I say supersymmetry is broken at low energy I mean that up to the energies we have studied in colliders supersymmetry is broken. This is an experimental observation. If string/M theory is correct there will be a supersymmetry breaking at some energy, but string/M theory is insufficienty developed to make a prediction of where this happens.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399038/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457834/2451 and links therein.